# Singer.io -> tap-postgres to target-redshift. getting error to move the data to redshift

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, singer-io

I am trying tap-postgres to target-redshift.
But am getting this error when writing data to redshift. I am reading from tap-postgres. tap-Postgres to target-csv is working fine.

tap-postgres -> conf.json

```
{
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 5432,
    "dbname": "singer",
    "user": "postgres",
    "password": "password",
    "schema": "public"
}
```

tap-catalog.json

```
{
  "streams": [
    {
      "table_name": "student",
      "stream": "singer-postgres",
      "metadata": [
        {
          "breadcrumb": [],
          "metadata": {
            "table-key-properties": [
              "id"
            ],
            "selected": true,
            "replication-method": "FULL_TABLE",
            "schema-name": "public",
            "database-name": "singer",
            "row-count": 9,
            "is-view": false
          }
        },
        {
          "breadcrumb": [
            "properties",
            "id"
          ],
          "metadata": {
            "sql-datatype": "integer",
            "inclusion": "automatic",
            "selected-by-default": true,
            "selected": true
          }
        },
        {
          "breadcrumb": [
            "properties",
            "name"
          ],
          "metadata": {
            "sql-datatype": "text",
            "inclusion": "available",
            "selected-by-default": true,
            "selected": true
          }
        },
        {
          "breadcrumb": [
            "properties",
            "email"
          ],
          "metadata": {
            "sql-datatype": "text",
            "inclusion": "available",
            "selected-by-default": true,
            "selected": true
          }
        }
      ],

      "tap_stream_id": "singer-public-demo",
      "schema": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": [
              "integer"
            ],
            "minimum": -2147483648,
            "maximum": 2147483647,
            "selected": true
          },
          "name": {
            "type": [
              "null",
              "string"
            ],
            "maxLength": 80,
            "selected": true
          },
          "email": {
            "type": [
              "null",
              "string"
            ],
            "maxLength": 80,
            "selected": true
          }
        },
        "definitions": {
          "sdc_recursive_integer_array": {
            "type": [
              "null",
              "integer",
              "array"
            ],
            "items": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/sdc_recursive_integer_array"
            }
          },
          "sdc_recursive_number_array": {
            "type": [
              "null",
              "number",
              "array"
            ],
            "items": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/sdc_recursive_number_array"
            }
          },
          "sdc_recursive_string_array": {
            "type": [
              "null",
              "string",
              "array"
            ],
            "items": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/sdc_recursive_string_array"
            }
          },
          "sdc_recursive_boolean_array": {
            "type": [
              "null",
              "boolean",
              "array"
            ],
            "items": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/sdc_recursive_boolean_array"
            }
          },
          "sdc_recursive_timestamp_array": {
            "type": [
              "null",
              "string",
              "array"
            ],
            "format": "date-time",
            "items": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/sdc_recursive_timestamp_array"
            }
          },
          "sdc_recursive_object_array": {
            "type": [
              "null",
              "object",
              "array"
            ],
            "items": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/sdc_recursive_object_array"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

target_redshift_config.json

```
{
  "redshift_host": "host_name",
  "redshift_port": 5439,
  "redshift_database": "database_name",
  "redshift_username": "user_name",
  "redshift_password": "password",
  "redshift_schema": "schema_name",
  "Trusted_Connection": "True",
  "default_column_length": 1000,
  "target_s3": {
    "aws_access_key_id": "AXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "aws_secret_access_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "bucket": "bigdata/phani",
    "key_prefix": "_tmp"
  },
  
   "schema":{
      "properties":{
         "id":{
            "inclusion":"available",
            "type":[
               "integer"
            ]
         },
         "name":{
            "inclusion":"available",
            "type":[
               "string"
            ]
         },
         "email":{
            "inclusion":"available",
            "type":[
               "string"
            ]
         }
      }
   }  
  
  
}
```

The error screenshot is below. Was looking for inputs on the below. Can you help on how to resolve the below error

```
phani@ubuntu:~$ ~/.virtualenvs/tap-postgres/bin/tap-postgres -c /home/phani/tap-postgres/conf.json --properties /home/phani/tap-postgres/tap-catalog.json | ~/.virtualenvs/target-redshift/bin/target-redshift  --config /home/phani/target-redshift/target_redshift_config.json > state.json 
/home/phani/.virtualenvs/tap-postgres/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
INFO Failed to retrieve SSL status
INFO Selected streams: ['singer-public-demo'] 
INFO No currently_syncing found
INFO Beginning sync of stream(singer-public-demo) with sync method(full)
INFO Stream singer-public-demo is using full_table replication
INFO Current Server Encoding: UTF8
INFO Current Client Encoding: UTF8
INFO hstore is UNavailable
INFO Beginning new Full Table replication 1600403309215
INFO select SELECT  "email" , "id" , "name" , xmin::text::bigint
                                      FROM "public"."student"
                                     ORDER BY xmin::text::bigint ASC with itersize 20000
INFO METRIC: {"type": "counter", "metric": "record_count", "value": 9, "tags": {}}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/phani/.virtualenvs/target-redshift/bin/target-redshift", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/home/phani/.virtualenvs/target-redshift/lib/python3.6/site-packages/target_redshift/__init__.py", line 55, in cli
    main(args.config)
  File "/home/phani/.virtualenvs/target-redshift/lib/python3.6/site-packages/target_redshift/__init__.py", line 28, in main
    password=config.get('redshift_password')
  File "/home/phani/.virtualenvs/target-redshift/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "host_url" (ip) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5439?
```

Comment: ~/.virtualenvs/tap-postgres/bin/tap-postgres -c /home/phani/tap-postgres/conf.json --properties /home/phani/tap-postgres/tap-catalog.json | ~/.virtualenvs/target-redshift/bin/target-redshift  --config /home/phani/target-redshift/target_redshift_config.json > state.json

Answer (score 0):

Your stack trace tells you that it is not able to connect to Redshift

```
File "/home/phani/.virtualenvs/target-redshift/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "host_url" (ip) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5439?
```

I would double check your connection details in `target_redshift_config.json` and make sure that you can connect to that DB from your IP. AWS loves being ultra-secure, sometimes to a point of painfulness, so it's possible your IP is restricted from accessing that Redshift instance. If that's the case you'll need to update the security policy on your Redshift DB.